# Vanishing printers under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, printing

What causes printer to 'vanish' from the CUPS printers.conf file under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? I have a network of DRBL booted workstations and one of the network served printers keeps 'vanishing'.

Here is the access_log from cups:

```
    circdesk2% sudo zless -X /var/log/cups/access_log.1.gz 
    localhost - - [08/Jun/2014:14:28:38 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 446 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
    localhost - - [08/Jun/2014:14:28:45 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1193 CUPS-Get-Devices -
    localhost - - [08/Jun/2014:14:29:32 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
    localhost - - [08/Jun/2014:14:33:37 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 162 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
    localhost - - [08/Jun/2014:14:46:30 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 166 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
```

What process do I need to kill or package to remove or service to disable to stop this from happening?  I don't need or want some 'helpful' daemon managing the printers on these machines.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem: cups_browsed, which I guess would be fine for a *laptop* but totally anoying for a *server* (or for *fixed* desktops / workstations).  'sudo apt-get purge cups_browsed' cured things.